# Разместить 9 кнопок на экране

Tags: java, android, ui

Необходимо разместить 9 кнопок матрицей 3 на 3 так, чтобы они равномерно занимали весь экран и были одинакового размера вне зависимости от длины размещенного на них текста.
Вроде ничего сложного, но не получается сделать. ((

Comment: А что не получается? Берёшь цикл и рисуешь. Проблемный участок кода есть? Или мне сделать?

Comment: @osrsoft, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: *TableLayout*, либо *GridView*.
У второго есть некоторые проблемы с TextView, лучше сначала попробовать первый.
Покажите, действительно, layout, с которым проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таки не проблема же.

1) Берем **LinearLayout** вертикальный на весь экран.

2) В него пихаем 3-и таких же горизонтальных с шириной на весь экран и с нулевой высотой при весе равном единице.

3) В них пихаем по 3-и кнопки с высотой равной высоте родителя и шириной нулевой при весе, опять таки равном единице.

4) ???

5) Profit!!!11one

**P.S.** Компилятор, правда, может начать ругаться на вложенные элементы с весом, но работать должно.

**P.S.** Ещё можно, по идее, с **GridLayout** поиграться, но, ИМХО, считаю что можно с ним не заморачиваться.

Answer (score 0):

Для такой разметки идеально подходит контейнер TableLayout .

использовать несколько вложенных контейнеров LinearLayout не рекомендуется для решения подобной задачи без крайней необходимости , так как это существенно сказывается на производительности